# Will an armv7-only app run on arm64 iOS devices?

Tags: ios, armv7, arm64

I'm working on an iOS app. To keep the binary small and for other technical reasons, I'd like to only build for armv7. I know that the App Store won't accept apps that don't provide an arm64 slice, but currently this is no issue (I'll add an arm64 slice later on). So here's my question:

**Will iPhones with arm64 CPUs (iPhone 5s, 6, 6s) run armv7-only apps?**

As far as I know, the CPUs are capable of running armv7 code. To support 32 bit apps, it is however necessary that the OS allows it and that the linked frameworks such as Foundation contain an armv7 slice. I can't test this myself as I have no access to an arm64 device.

Comment: "the linked frameworks such as Foundation contain an armv7 slice", that's exactly what's going on in arm64 iOS - it contains two sets of the libraries in the form of two dyld cache files for armv7s and arm64. armv7s is compatible with armv7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compatibility table will help you:
[image]

Reference: [Apple Documents: Device Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)

Comment: Thanks. I stumbled across this page before, but obviously didn't read it thoroughly enough.